# Move-Item, but keep newest if conflict

Tags: powershell

I got a few foreach loops, where I am doing some if and elseif's in. They're basically set to sort out a bunch of files based on their name.
But I got a particular case, where there are a few files, that aparantly exist in 2 different locations. But I want to keep the newest file always.

My code looks like this

```
# Variable for destination folder
$CreoRod = "C:\Test\Creo"
# Variable for source folder
$97MappeRod = "C:\Test\97"
# Variable to get each item in source folder
$97Files = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $97MappeRod
# Variable to get each item in destination folder
$CreoRodFiles = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $CreoRod

# Foreach loop to move files from source folder to corresponding destination folder 
foreach ($file in $97Files) {
    if ($file -like "0*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\0xxx"
    } elseif ($file -like "48*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\48xxx"
    } elseif ($file -like "49*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\49xxx"
    } elseif ($file -like "97*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\97xxx"
    } elseif ($file -like "98*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\98xxx"
    } elseif ($file -like "99*") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\99xxx"
    } elseif ($file -notmatch "config.pro") {
        Move-Item -Path "$97MappeRod\$file" -Destination "$CreoRod\Diverse"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something to make it compare with existing file, and if the existing file is newer, then delete the current. But if it is older then replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it might help you with the logic, first you can use a **helper [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2)** to test if a file with the same name exists in the destination and if it does, test if it should be replaced (`$true` if newer or if the destination does not have a file with that name) or remove the source file (`$false`).

For the multiple `if` conditions, I would recommend you to replace them for a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) which gives more readability.

```
function ShouldMove {
    param($File, $Destination)
    $testPath = Join-Path $Destination -ChildPath $File.Name
    if(Test-Path $testPath) {
        # if the destination folder contains this file name
        $destFile = Get-Item $testPath
        if($File.CreationTime -gt $destFile.CreationTime) {
            # if the source file is newer return `$true`
            return $true
        }
        # else `$false`
        return $false
    }
    # if destination does not have this file, return `$true`
    $true

}

foreach ($file in $97Files) {
    $destination = switch -Wildcard($file.Name) {
        "0*"  { "$CreoRod\0xxx" ; break }
        "48*" { "$CreoRod\48xxx"; break }
        "49*" { "$CreoRod\49xxx"; break }
        "97*" { "$CreoRod\97xxx"; break }
        "98*" { "$CreoRod\98xxx"; break }
        "99*" { "$CreoRod\99xxx"; break }
        { $_ -notmatch "config.pro" } { "$CreoRod\Diverse" }
        Default {
            Write-Warning "No condition was met, ignoring $($file.Name)"
        }
    }
    
    if(-not $destination) { continue }
    if(ShouldMove -File $file -Destination $destination) {
        # `-Force` to replace it
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -Destination $destination -Force
        continue
    }
    # if `ShouldMove` returned `$false` then, instead of moving
    # the file, delete the source
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName
}
```

Comment: Man, I was still trying to comprehend what they were asking lol glad you got it!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i'm not sure I got it LOL, just a hunch :P

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the feedback!
Regarding the switch, yeah I should definently use it more. I am still not a PowerShell guru, but I try to learn. It was a lot worse before lol.

I think this is the right solution. It seems like it it is a lot of what I need, which helps me a ton to create a proper logic behind it. Thank you!

Comment: it was my pleasure @HeineKristensen happy to help

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is about moving file to a new destination folder if the file name meets certain conditions.
Then, if a file with that name already exists in the target destination folder, move that file **only** if it is newer than the existing file.

If that assumption is correct, you can do:

```
$CreoRod    = "C:\Test\Creo"   # destination
$97MappeRod = "C:\Test\97"     # source
$97Files     = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $97MappeRod

foreach ($file in $97Files) {
    # determine destination path
    $targetFolder = $null
    if ($file.Name -match '^(0|48|49|97|98|99)') { $targetFolder = '{0}xxx' -f $matches[1] }
    elseif ($file.Name -notlike '*config.pro*')  { $targetFolder = 'Diverse' }

    # file name was not recognized, so skip this one and proceed with the rest
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($targetFolder)) { continue }

    # complete the target destination path
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $CreoRod -ChildPath $targetFolder

    # try and get the file already in the targetFolder
    $existingFile = Get-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $targetFolder -ChildPath $file.Name) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($existingFile) {
        # a file with that name already exists, check if the file from the source folder is newer
        $canMoveThis = ($existingFile.LastWriteTime -lt $file.LastWriteTime)
    }
    else {
        $canMoveThis = $true
        # should we create the target path if it doesn't exist yet?
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    }

    if ($canMoveThis) {
        # all clear, move the file
        $file | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: It is correct, I am trying to move files from 2 different locations, and save them to a new location, based on their name. The files have a naming structure of starting with e.g. 97, 98, 99, etc. So they could be named 9851202 or something like that. Those files has to go to a new corresponding folder. But the problem I'm facing, is the chances of meeting dublicates. So if I got a file called 9712311 in one location and 9712311 in the other location, I want it to keep the newest of the files. There is also a chance of a file being maned 9704849, which is why I am using the wildcard ater 2 char